# tup monitor not working?

Tags: linux, command-line, tup

I'm trying to use tup to auto compile my files.  After init, I can use `tup upd` in the command line, but whenever I do `tup monitor -a`, nothing happens. The command executes, there is no result/error/response, and when I change a file, tup does not pick up the change and auto compile.  What is going on?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/tup-users/tQwJlYPdd44/5Vn6knm9pAoJ This might help you. Thanks & Regards, Alok Thaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed tup using apt-get, but I uninstalled that and installed it from the website, everything worked